# How to get Current Lat Lng position on GMAPS API V3?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm trying to calculate my route, from my current position to the specific location (var: end). How I suppose to get my LatLng from my current position ? Thx

Here's my Code :

```
function calcRoute() {
var start = "How to get this LatLng ?";
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.28529,106.871542);
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need you use the gps on your phone. Here is a link on how to set it all up: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: I got my device location, but I just need the Lat and Lng number ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Location object (lets call it location), all you need to do is `LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())` and you will have a LatLng object. `location.getLatitude()` returns a double corresponding to the latitude in degrees and `location.getLongitude()` returns the same but for longitude. See the documentation for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html